# IE6 crashes with this jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, crash, internet-explorer, window

The following code crashes IE6 every time. It keeps refreshing the page and crashes after a minute:

```
$(window).bind("load resize", function () {
    var hnf = $('#header').height() + $('#footer').height();
    $('#main').height($(window).height() - (hnf));
    $('.fluid').height($('#main').outerHeight());
    $('#content').width($('#main').width() - $("#aside").width() - 90);
});
```

..whats causing it?

EDIT: Okay the "resize" in `$(window).bind("load resize", function () {` is causing it, how do I fix?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time IE6 made me angry I'd be rich, and the angriest rich guy on earth.

Comment: You'll get a a lot of rep for that comment. I hope I get my solution though. :)

Comment: Is this happening with our without XP SP2? Because IE6 without XP SP2 crashes all the time with jQuery, SP2 solves it.

Comment: Even if it's a browser bug, you might try different versions of jQuery to see if one works. Then, if you find a working version, you can look at the source code to see what initiates the bug in IE6 and how it was "fixed" or "not broken" by the working version. This is a far stretch.

Comment: The `Test Swarm project for jQuery` provides testing results for supported browsers. Choose a commit from this page:
http://testswarm.com/user/jqueryui/ 
Then you'll see the status of each corresponding jQuery parts for each supported browser like this: 
http://testswarm.com/job/111/
You'll find answers about failures (red marks) for various browsers so you'll know if it's not just your computer.
I think they only use the latest browser service packs though, so likely no official test results for less than SP2 on IE6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix [Drew Wills links to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000945/ie6-crashes-with-this-jquery/2000990#2000990) sounds like it should work. Try:

```
var prevHeight;
$(window).bind("load resize", function () {
  var height = $(window).height();
  if ( prevHeight == height ) 
     return; // hack to prevent recursion in IE6
  prevHeight = height;

  // resize content
  var hnf = $('#header').height() + $('#footer').height();
  $('#main').height(height - (hnf));
  $('.fluid').height($('#main').outerHeight());
  $('#content').width($('#main').width() - $("#aside").width() - 90);
});
```

Feel free to pretty that up a bit (attach *prevHeight* to something else, etc).

Comment: In that case, you'll need something a bit more clever... Try the fix Drew Wills links to.

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though IE6 incorrectly fires the onResize event even when the document body dimensions change.  Here's a [link with more information](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/ie6_fires_onresize).

I would look for a non-jQuery way to do what you want.  If you use CSS to control the fixed-size elements of your page, won't the browser take care of the variable-size elements on its own?

Comment: Thanks, but I hardly know any JS to implement the fix on my code. Can you please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have to do with the fact that you are trying to set the height and width without CSS. I am not sure but if I was going to do it I would use the JQUERY .css() method to set he height and width. so it would look like this,

```
$(window).bind("load resize", function () {
    var hnf = $('#header').height() + $('#footer').height();
    $('#main').css("height", ($(window).height() - hnf));
    $('.fluid').css("height", ($('#main').outerHeight()));
    $('#content').css("width", ($('#main').width() - $("#aside").width() - 90));
});
```

This might not work I did not test it.